# How can I get this shimmery/pearlescent fluid?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I was wondering if it was possible to get this kind of pearlescent fluid color or whatever its called.

[image]

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this. It's just a Noise Texture with the distortion and detail turned up, and flattened a bit on the Z-axis. I used the Noise as a Mix Factor for the colors and also used the colors for a bit of Subsurface Scattering. I used the inverse of the Noise for a bit of Transmission so the dark areas look more "gooey". I upped the Metallic value a bit as well, because polishes like that often contain a metallic "sheen: component.

[image: Polish]