# How can I achieve a procedurally generated mixed color effect on the sides of a dice object?

Tags: texturing, materials, color, procedural

I have a simple dice object with a material node for the side color and a material node for the dot color.

How can I achieve this mixed color effect on the sides of the dice:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not so unlike [this recent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211877/35559)